# physical memory usage is high on production sql server

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, memory-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL 2008 Memory Usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/236683/sql-2008-memory-usage)

I'm going threw high physical memory usage in SQL Server.
It always around 90%.When i reboot the server, it will initially good but end of the day it will around 90to 95% physical memory usage.

```
Configurataion : Windows SQL server 2008r2
Processor Intel Xeon CPU E5450 @3.00GHZ
Installed memory 32.GB
System type: 64bit operating system.
I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64) Sep 16 2010 19:43:16 Copyright (c) 1988-2008
Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: ).
Allocate memory to instance is 26214MB.
```

Can some one help me on this please.?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [top-voted answer to the question this is a duplicate of](https://serverfault.com/a/236715/118258), this is expected behavior.

MSSQL Server will take about all the memory it can get its hands on, and it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: technically, he said that he set the memory allocation for SQL to less than the full 32GB. That being said, he set the allocation for almost 80% and then you throw in OS memory usage, etc, and you are probably right there at 90% total usage.

Comment: @Rex  Thanks, I misread the system memory in the question as originally formatted.  And I agree.  Worrying about ~3 GB of memory allocation on a Windows SQL server is not going to be a very fruitful exercise.